# MySQL, RDS, Lock timeout

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-rds

I am creating an app that uses a MySQL instance of RDS, accessed by node and python programs. The node side is fine, and up until a few days ago the python side was fine as well. Now the python program is failing on simple queries:

I am running the queries through a context manager like so:

```
with safeExecute(dbConnection.cursor()) as cursor:
    log('about to run SQL')
    sql = """UPDATE ts
             SET ts.fails = ts.fails + 1,
                ts.attempts = ts.attempts + 1
             WHERE ts.id = 206 """
    cursor.execute(sql)
    log('sql executed')

@contextmanager
def safeExecute(cursor):
    try:
        yield cursor
        log('attempting to commit')
        dbConnection.commit()
        log('committed')
    except MySQLdb.OperationalError as e:
            dbConnection.rollback()
        log("--CRITICAL--")    
        traceback.print_exc()
        sys.exit(1)
    except Exception as e:
        dbConnection.rollback()
        log("Caught DB exception: ")
        traceback.print_exc()
        sys.stdout.flush()
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```

The console log will look like this:

```
about to run sql
sql executed 
attempting to commit
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
      OR
OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

Strangely, this error is fairly intermitten, and will not always get to the same point. Sometimes `attempting to commit` will be present, and other times it will never get past `cursor.execute()`.

I have a 2 other similar queries, just updating various counters. It will sometimes execute all 3 without a problem, and sometimes get stuck on one of them. This app should not have any concurrency problems, it spends ~30 seconds processing, and then runs these queries above, all sequentially (so there shouldn't be any race conditions).

However, looking at the open tables it doesn't appear to be locked (the query was running when I executed the following)

```
mysql> show open tables where in_use>0;
+------------+------------+--------+-------------+
| Database   | Table      | In_use | Name_locked |
+------------+------------+--------+-------------+
| tearsheets | tearsheets |      1 |           0 |
+------------+------------+--------+-------------+
```

`Show processlist` also doesn't reveal anything. In fact it shows that the connection is sleeping:

```
 ID      | USER       | HOST            | DB         | COMMAND | TIME | STATE     | INFO                                                              |
 1230255 | <username>   | <ip-address> | <ts table> | Sleep   |   42 |           | NULL
```

the `state` is blank, there is no text there...

How can I further debug this? I'm not sure what else to look at.

Comment: as a side note, if you were using innodb then i highly recommend innotop for viewing lock information. it will show you which transactions are involved when locks are blocked by other transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by simply closing the connection after each transaction, and then re-opening a new transaction for the next database interaction. Not sure what the original cause of my issue was, but this seems to be working now.